# SQL Server CE Schema Compare Tool

Tags: sql-server-ce, database-schema

Is there any tool which schema compares directly 2 SQL CE databases. VS2010 not working for CE as well as every commercial tool i have seen. How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you compare them on the SQL Server side?  CE databases should be replicas of a master db.

Comment: I don't understand how to achieve this since you cant attach a CE database on the SQL Server. I don't use replicas of a master db. You always follow this method?

Comment: When I've worked with CE databases in the past, we've started with a SQL Server db and then used merge replication or RDA to read or write data and ActiveSync to sync the disconnected device when it's back in its cradle.  If you don't have a master db your CE dbs came from, you can't compare them that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature of SDF Viewer. You can create a script of the differences between both schema and data of two SQLCE databases. Download available at [Flyhoward Ltd](http://www.flyhoward.com/SDF_Viewer.aspx)